# Import an existing Windows Server on Hyper-V into Windows Virtual Desktop on Azure?

Tags: azure

We are in the process of moving some servers into Azure. We have a current rather complex setup on one server which would be golden to get migrated over to Azure and we'd like to use Virtual Desktop as that would suit our needs nicely.
According to both our tech-sales rep and Azure Developers Support it should be possible to do this migration and both have pointed to the "migration tool":

> *Use Azure Migrate to discover, assess, and migrate on-premises infrastructure, applications, and data to Azure. Azure Migrate supports assessment and migration of on-premises VMware VMs, Hyper-V VMs, physical servers, other virtualized VMs, databases, web apps, and virtual desktops.*

Also from the About page of Azure Migrate:

> ***Virtual desktops***: Assess your on-premises virtual desktop infrastructure (VDI) and migrate it to Windows Virtual Desktop in Azure.

What neither the Azure Support (which IMHO seems to be using Google as much as I do) cant figure out is how to then get the migrated server into Virtual Desktop...

In Virtual Desktop there is only the option of creating a new server...

Anyone that has a clue?
Firstly, is it at all possible, and secondly, how is it done?

Comment: This video seems to do the trick: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrccmB01D_s

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image